# Why can't I mix text rows with image rows in table layout?

Tags: android, textview, row, tablelayout

My mainactivity Android .xml table layout is a simple table of images, 3 columns by 4 rows. Everything is set to match_parent width, height and weight 1, which renders slightly wrong in the GUI editor but okay on my phone.

If I then add a row in the .xml before the bottom row to add text labels, it either doesn't render the row at all, or, after a little poking, renders the text but cuts off the bottom with the last row.

The following is the .xml, long winded but very simple and repetitive.

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stretchColumns="*"       
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="match_parent"
    android1:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <TableRow
        android1:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x2"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:clickable="true"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_2x"
            android1:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x3"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_3x"
            android1:tag="3" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x4"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_4x"
            android1:tag="4" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android1:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x5"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_5x"
            android1:tag="5" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x6"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_6x"
            android1:tag="6" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x7"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_7x"
            android1:tag="7" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android1:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x8"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_8x"
            android1:tag="8" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x9"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_9x"
            android1:tag="9" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/x10"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="SetTable"
            android1:padding="5dp"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/menu_10x"
            android1:tag="10" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android1:id="@+id/TableRow01"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:layout_weight="1" >

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_span="2"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:text="Left two buttons"
            android1:textColor="#000000"
            android1:textSize="16dp"
            android1:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android1:id="@+id/textView1"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:text="Right button"
            android1:textColor="#000000"
            android1:textSize="16dp"
            android1:textStyle="normal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android1:id="@+id/TableRow5"
        android1:layout_width="match_parent"
        android1:layout_height="match_parent"
        android1:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/ImageView07"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="LaunchPR"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/pushbutton_1"
            android1:tag="1" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/ImageView08"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="LaunchPR"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/pushbutton_1"
            android1:tag="2" />

        <ImageView
            android1:id="@+id/ImageView09"
            android1:layout_width="match_parent"
            android1:layout_height="match_parent"
            android1:layout_weight="1"
            android1:onClick="LaunchPR"
            android1:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android1:src="@drawable/pushbutton_2"
            android1:tag="3" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Can you also post the code used to add that extra row?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased myself badly. It's all in the .xml; I'm not adding it dynamically. I mean I had the table working with the images and then added the new row with the editor/xml. ;)

Comment: Do you know what those attributes that you used for some of your views do? I'm especially referring to the `layout_weight` which you seem to have used on all the views.

Comment: According to the documentation, the weight should be a relative scaling factor. With a total weight of 3, and each element having a weight of 1, each element is scaled to 1/3 of the width. Likewise with the height. Only the weight doesn't seem to work properly with rows with a text field.

Comment: @ Luksprog - you're right, the row weights are unnecessary with the table set to scale to view. Add that as an answer and I'll tick it for you for the points. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the the `TableLayout` to fill the parent(`match_parent`) you don't need the `layout_weight` attribute. You would need to use that `layout_weight`(on the `TableRows`) if you're planning to make the `TableRows` to occupy equal space vertically(for example, if you have 4 rows then you would set the `android:weightSum="4"` on the `TableLayout` and `android:layout_weight="1"` on the `TableRows` to make four equally sized vertically rows(filling the screen)).

Also, the `android:stretchColumns="*"` property will stretch all of your table's column so you don't need the layout_weight on the children of the `TableRow`.

Comment: Trying my interface on larger screens, this doesn't appear to be true. I need the weight sum of 2 in my main TableLayout and each row of weight 1, otherwise it only draws to half the screen height.

Comment: @TickledPink If you have 4 rows then the `weightSum` should be 4(and the weight equally divided between the rows). I don't see why this would fail on a larger screen.

Comment: I have nested tables. The main containing table has two rows splitting the screen into top and bottom halves, and was only fitting the top half of the screen on a large display until I added the weights.